# close dropdown for input-"search" on -webikit-search-cancel-button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I have an input box with type="search" and below that a list of options that shows in a dropdown when the input box is clicked. I managed to get this to work.
However the issue I run into now: whenever the 'X' in the input box (the search-cancel-button) is clicked the input text in the input box is deleted but the dropdown doesn't disappear.
How could I fix this?

Below is my code:

```css
.form .formtextbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.form .formtextbox .options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--white);
  min-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 0px #0000001F;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.form .formtextbox:focus-within .options {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="">
  <fieldset class="form">
    <div class="formtextbox">
      <input title="search_form_title" type="search" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="options">
        <ul unselectable="on">
          <li>apple</li>
          <li>banana</li>
          <li>pineapple</li>
          <li>strawberry</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="formbutton">
      <input type="submit" hidden />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a little JavaScript. What I have done is added a function which listens for the `X` button click event and then hides the dropdown options. The `X` button does not dispatch the click event, but rather an `input` event. We can listen for the same and hide the dropdown options when it occurs. Additionally, I have added `ids` to input and options element to refer them in Javascript. You can use follow other ways well. Something like:

```js
document.getElementById('search-input').addEventListener('input', function() {
  var options = document.getElementById('options-container');
  if (this.value.length === 0) {
    options.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    options.style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

```css
.form .formtextbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.form .formtextbox .options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--white);
  min-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 0px #0000001F;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.form .formtextbox:focus-within .options {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="">
  <fieldset class="form">
    <div class="formtextbox">
      <input id="search-input" title="search_form_title" type="search" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
      <div id="options-container" class="options">
        <ul unselectable="on">
          <li>apple</li>
          <li>banana</li>
          <li>pineapple</li>
          <li>strawberry</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="formbutton">
      <input type="submit" hidden />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```